# React router redirect re-rendering the same component it is called from, not redirected to the specified path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to redirect to a component from another one, after a state change  using

in Component B.js, I want a redirect onclick as below:

```
 if(this.state.something) return <Redirect to= "/" />
```

in Component A.js

```
`

import { Route,Switch,BrowserRouter  as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

    const  ComponentA  = () => { 

    return (  

        <Router>
            <React.Fragment>

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/somepath/:name/:id/"  component={ComponentXYZ} />
                    <Route  path='/' exact component={Log} />

                </Switch> 

            </React.Fragment>
        </Router>

)} ;
export default ComponentA ;`
```

My problem is that the on redirect the URL changes to `'localhost:3000/'` but the component A is rendering the route with component '`abc`' instead of '`Log`'. If I refresh the browser, the `Log` component renders and displays the view. I tried `history.push` and also `withRouter` to solve the issue, but no luck. Kindly help,I'm new to react programming. TIA :)

Comment: You try add exact in Route(/abc)

Comment: I tried ,but it doesn't work. When I check in the React devTools,it shows that its rendering Route/abc on submit and however, the url does change to '/' . And on refreshing the browser, it renders Route '/ '

Comment: In project, Do you use redux? I think your code isn't wrong. Please update full code in component A???

Comment: History.push() is the correct code you are looking for in this case either way (I know you said it didn't work)... as for why it isn't working your code isn't very helpful

Comment: @san I've updated the code for ComponentA and I'm not using Redux.

Comment: I think it isn't due to the above code. I tested on my project is here: https://jsfiddle.net/san93st/n5u2wwjg/200328/

Comment: @san Thank you for confirming. However, do you know what is causing the error ,in general

Comment: @san, I was trying your jsfiddle. it looks like the `setState` is not changing the state of `showRedirect` onClick. but the code looks fine .Can you pls check